# Как удалить текст после слова?

Tags: c#, строки

Имеется ини файл

```
[Account_0]

Login=Иванов Федор Иванович
```

Добираюсь до строки

```
string[] chlines = File.ReadAllLines(path);
foreach (string chline in chlines)
{
    if (chline.Contains("Login="))
    {

    }
}
```

Нахожу эту строку все без проблем, вот как теперь мне затереть **Иванов Федор Иванович** и написать вместо него другое имя? Спасибо

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Например так:

```
string str = "Login=Иванов Федор Иванович";
string key = "Login=";
int pos = str.IndexOf(key) + key.Length;
if(pos >= key.Length)
    str = str.Replace(str.Substring(pos), "Петров Петр Петрович");
```